# How to get different timezone date in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to know what is current date and time in South Africa.

How i can check what is the current time and date across different timezone in oracle?

I will add timezone values in data table and from that can i get current date and time?

I have one Country table in that i will save timezone as per the country. Now in procedure i have to check one date from other table against all countries is the current date or not.
So query: SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Africa/Johannesburg'
FROM   DUAL; will not solve my issue.

Comment: Typically timestamps are stored in SQL databases using a single timezone, usually UTC.  You should worry about your particular timezone after you have queried out your data in the presentation layer.

Comment: Can you please suggest me suppose if i add all timezone in one column of the table and from that i have to get time zone? select SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone timezone_column_name from dual; I have to check for multiple countries in procedure depending on one variable. so i can not hard code timezone value in query.

Answer (score 4):

Use `SYSTIMESTAMP` to get the current system timestamp and `AT TIME ZONE '<time zone>'` to change to a different time zone:

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Africa/Johannesburg'
FROM   DUAL;
```

A list of time zone names can be found with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM gv$timezone_names;
```

You could even pass the time zone name as a variable rather than using a hard-coded text literal:

```
SELECT TZNAME,
       SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE TZNAME AS current_time
FROM   gv$timezone_names;
```

Comment: Can you please suggest me suppose if i add all timezone in one column of the table and from that i have to get time zone? select SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone timezone_column_name from dual;
I have to check for multiple countries in procedure depending on one variable. so i can not hard code timezone value in query.

Comment: @Bala You do not have to hard-code the time zone name - you can pass it as a variable. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/184b5/22)

Comment: DECLARE   timezoneName        VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN
  timezoneName := 'Africa/Johannesburg';
  select SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone timezoneName from dual;  
END;
I am getting error for this as: "PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement". can you please help here, to find issue? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Bala As the exception says, use `SELECT ... INTO variable_name FROM ...`

Comment: hi Sir not working 
DECLARE     timezoneName        VARCHAR2(128);
            tempVar TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  timezoneName := 'Africa/Johannesburg';
  select SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone timezoneName INTO tempVar from dual;  
END;
Error at line 1
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
ORA-06512: at line 5

Comment: @Bala Not sure why it is not working in a `SELECT` statement but, instead, you can do it all in PL/SQL - [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/184b5/32)

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
       SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone 'Africa/Johannesburg' south_africa_time
from dual;
```

You could refer this link for all time zone values

[**TIME Zones**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13866_04/webconf.904/b10877/timezone.htm)

Comment: Can you please suggest me suppose if i add all timezone in one column of the table and from that i have to give time zone? 
select 
       SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone timezone_column_name 
from dual;